# podcast syncing and playing from multiple computers

Tags: mp3, streaming, podcasts, cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synchronize Podcasts across multiple computers with iTunes (on Windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/72041/synchronize-podcasts-across-multiple-computers-with-itunes-on-windows)

I listen to a lot of podcasts and I would like to be able to build a single playlist and access it across multiple devices - laptop, desktop and even phone if possible. Often the podcast is an hour long, and it would be fantastic to be able to start listening to a podcast on my desktop, pause it, then resume listening on my laptop or phone from the same point.

Of course, it would also be wonderful to syncronize podcast downloading and management between multiple devices. Perhaps this is the iCloud solution from Apple...

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/72041/synchronize-podcasts-across-multiple-computers-with-itunes-on-windows) is an earlier post that suggested two services for syncing itune libraries.

Or you could use [always sync](http://allwaysync.com/) or [drop box](http://www.dropbox.com) to sync your podcast libraries.